# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80000013

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, silverlight-5.0

I have problem. I try run WP7 app on Win Phone8. All work good, but sometimes I have `UNHANDLED EXCEPTION` with message:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80000013. This is occurs when I go on the page where including Gart library

```
<ARControls:ARDisplay x:Name="ARDisplayy" d:LayoutOverrides="Width">  
    <ARControls:VideoPreview x:Name="VideoPreview" />
    <ARControls:WorldView x:Name="WorldView" />
</ARControls:ARDisplay>
```

I don't know, why it is happened. May be someone encountered such a problem?

Comment: That's a strange error number... in decimal, it is '2147483667'... I found some disassembled source code for the `HResult struct` at [DotnetInside.com](http://dotnetinside.com/cn/framework/v4.0.30319/PresentationCore/HRESULT) and this number is *not* found inside it as an error code. Did you have any inner `Exception`s? If so, please provide details.

Comment: after an unknown event handler is triggered, I get message: An unhandled exception of type: "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" в System.Windows.ni.dll                                             And my stacktrace                           at Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureDevice.GetProperty(Guid propertyId)
   at Microsoft.Devices.Camera.GetVideoPortName()
   at Microsoft.Devices.Camera.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InitializeVideoSession>b__1()

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error using the ARM version of GART.WP8.dll